# Getting the current date and time and appending it to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create strings in javascript that contain the current time.

How can I create two strings like the following, but with the current timestamp?

```
itemTimestamp = "Itemized at 2014-05-01, 11:11 PM"
itemFilename = "itemized_at_2014_05_01_11_11_pm.png"
```

Comment: I want to create both based on the current day/time.

Comment: Look up `.toISOString()`

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLE:

**http://jsfiddle.net/gkQ7y/9/**

```
function format(date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month; 
    day = day < 10 ? '0' + day : day; 

    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime ="Itemized at "+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+", "+hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
}

var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = format(d);
var replaced = format(d).replace(/[ :-]/g,"_").replace(",","");
document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = replaced+".png";
```